# How to Build a Node.js project for deployment copy?

Tags: node.js, webpack, deployment

1. I want to build a node.js project for deployment on azure.
2. In Package.json in script section "build": "webpack" line I've added.
3. When I run the command in terminal "npm run build".
   'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command error throws.

So what is the correct script in Package.json for build? And is there any other alternative to build my node.js project for deploying on Azure or any other cloud service?

Comment: Do you have `webpack` in your package.json as a devDependency or dependency? If not, it likely isn't installed. You can install using `npm install webpack --save-dev`. 
You'll likely also need to configure webpack according to your project if you haven't already.

Comment: installed this webpack..now when I run npm run build, the following error occurs...Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Comment: Have you configured Webpack?